# Backbone events not triggered

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I'm trying to capture an event with backbone i got an html like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="head"> 
    <title>Con RequireJS</title>
    <script data-main="Scripts/main" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <button class="btnAuthenticate">Login with FourSquare</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And i'm trying to capture de event on click of that button with

```
events : {
'click .btnAuthenticate' : 'doAction' 
}
```

But when i create the view with

```
view = new thatView( {model:aModel, tagName: 'div', className: 'container' } ) ;
```

The el appears to be right in console

```
console.log(view.el)
```

get's me

```
<div class="container><div>
```

but the event does not work!
If instead i call

```
view = new thatView({el:'body'});
```

It does what it's suppose to, but then i can't append to the el i want! 
Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define `tagName: 'div', className: 'container'` Backbone will create a *new* `div.container` element. If you however want to reference an already existing DOM node then you should use `el` instead. I guess this should work for you:

```
view = new thatView({model:aModel, el: $('.container')});
```

Just make sure you create a view after DOM loaded.

More info http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor